# How do you combine URL fragments in Java the same way browsers do?

Tags: java, url, scala, browser

**NOTE**: *I am asking for real world problem, not for theoretical purpose; see the last part of the question -- the same way browsers do the job.*

---

Usually you would see the answer:

```
new java.net.URL(new java.net.URL(base_url),rel_url).toString
```

(**base_url** and **rel_url** are **String**). In my case **base_url** is the URL of page I fetched, **rel_url** comes from "<a href=..." value, so it might be even single "#" character (for example).

However such code does not work for URL fragments, like such two pieces:

> htpp://www.hello.com/1.html
>
> ?p=2

I tested Firefox, Chromium, Opera, Konqueror, "Web Browser" (Gnome modesty ;-D) -- all of them combine those URLs as:

> htpp://www.hello.com/1.html?p=2

With code as above I get:

> htpp://www.hello.com/?p=2

### Question

How do you combine URL fragments, in a ready for world manner?

*I hope there is already handy library for that, before I start doing parsing by myself ;-).*

Comment: @JamesBlack: What if `rel_url` starts with `../`?

Comment: Concatenate the strings? `?p=2` isn't a URL.

Comment: @Dᴀᴠᴇ Nᴇᴡᴛᴏɴ, for web browser it is. I am asking for solution for dealing with real world, not for theory.

Comment: @macias Just to verify, what is the content of rel_url?

Comment: @macias No, Dave is correct. "?p=2" is not a URL so to speak. It can be PART of a URL though. I would also recommend concatenating the strings and then turning them into a URL.

Comment: is you relative url always a complete query string (something like ?param=value&param1=value1)? or it may ba a part of a query string?

Comment: @Aaron McIver, both are strings.

Comment: @Max, simple concatenating does not work, see SLaks comment.

Comment: @Giovanni, relative part (rel_url) contains whatever exists in wide, wild world web. And I have to deal with it as well as regular browsers.

Comment: @SLaks - If you know you are putting a query parameter at the end, then just make certain there is no trailing '/' first, then append.  There is no magic bullet to do this, just building the strings up.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You are misunderstanding what a URL is.  `?p=2` is a *query string*, not a relative URL.  (You may also find `#foo`, which is usually called a *fragment identifier* or *reference* and is most commonly used to jump to a section of a long document).  The full scheme for URIs is [described on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URI_scheme#Generic_syntax) among many other places (you can also find the differences between URIs and URLs in various places).

Anyway, relative URLs refer *only to the path* part of the URL--it is whether the path is absolute or relative.  If you have a query string and wish to attach it to an existing URL (which does not have a query string), just append it to the string.  If you don't know whether you have a query string, you can use the methods in the URL class to test for it.

If you want to replicate what browsers do, given a full URL `url` and a String `s`,

```
if (s.startsWith("?") || s.startsWith("#")) new java.net.URL(url.toString + s)
else new java.net.URL(url, s)
```

should do the trick.  (I don't know the exact code that different browsers use, but this replicates the behavior that you describe of appending a query string if that is all that is provided in a href.) If you don't know whether your existing URLs might have query strings or not, then you can

```
if (s.startsWith("#")) new java.net.URL(url.toString.takeWhile(_ != '#') + s)
else if (s.startsWith("?")) new java.net.URL(url.toString.takeWhile(_ != '?') + s)
else new java.net.URL(url, s)
```

Comment: Why do you assume I don't understand something? I have "stream" of such pairs, and I have combine them. I re-title the question to avoid further off-topic comments. So your answer is simply -- no cookie, DIY. It is OK answer of course, but I hoped there is something already in existence (y2011 after all), combining those fragments is not rocket science, yet it is easy to make an error. (question updated)

Comment: @macias - I think there is no cookie in Java; I'm sure you can find some library that does it.  My complaint was that you were using the wrong terminology, and then complaining that a library that uses the correct terminology is not doing what you want.

Comment: Saying is not complaining, I mean it. I am looking for the tool to do the job, that's all. Thank you for the code!