# How can I combine two urls the same way a browser does?

Tags: c#, url, browser

I'm writing some kind of a page scraper, and one of the things I'm looking to do is combine the current url with an url fragment extracted from the current page.

Like this:

```
if (WebPath.IsAbsolute(urlFragment))
    links.Add(new Uri(urlFragment));
else
    links.Add(new Uri(currentUrl, urlFragment));
```

Easy peasy - this approach works most of the time, for both relative and absolute Uris.

*However*, some pages look like http://example.com/couple/of/folders/, with the url fragment [couple/of/otherfolders/](http://example.com/couple/of/otherfolders/). And every single browser out there interprets that as http://example.com/couple/of/otherfolders.

Of course, my code yields http://example.com/couple/of/folders/couple/of/otherfolders. Which totally looks correct from the Uri's point of view - but I don't get how a browser can interpret this otherwise.

Now, I've searched for a solution to this problem, but I only found people who didn't know how to combine two urls, so that didn't get me very far. Closest thing I found was this question: [How do you combine URL fragments in Java the same way browsers do?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8244181/how-do-you-combine-url-fragments-in-java-the-same-way-browsers-do) , but the answer doesn't tackle my particular problem.

Does anybody know what I'm missing?

---

Edit - this is the IsAbsolute method (I know I should replace it with new Uri(link).IsAbsoluteUri):

```
public static bool IsAbsolute(string path)
{
    var uppercasePath = path.ToUpper();
    return uppercasePath.StartsWith("HTTP://") || uppercasePath.StartsWith("HTTPS://");
}
```

Comment: Browsers would never interpret it like that, as there’s no leading slash. Assuming there is a leading slash, [`Uri` works properly.](http://ideone.com/kAkf98)

Comment: @minitech See http://www.goominet.com/unspeakable-vault/vault/1/ for an example - check out the Next link

Comment: @Vlad: Ah… sorry. The document has a `<base>` element, which is a horrible thing that you need to handle separately. So check for `<base>`, get its `href`, use that instead of `currentUrl` if it exists.

Comment: Dude, you rule, please post this as an answer so I can accept it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Normally, browsers wouldn’t do that. But when there’s a `<base>` element, [its `href` replaces the current page’s URL for the page’s URL-resolving purposes](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/document-metadata.html#the-base-element).

Check for a `<base>` and use it in place of `currentUrl` if it exists.

<sup>Also, thanks for reminding me to fix all my scrapers!</sup>

Comment: Thanks again, I had no idea this element exists.